# Can I uses swift library on iPad Playground?

Tags: swift-playground

I'm trying to uses swift playground on iPad.

It supports all of iOS classes.

But I can't find this features

- How can I import GitHub library?
- How can I create multiple Swift files?

Anyone know about this?

Comment: If my answer answers your question, please accept it to mark to the community that it contained a solution to your problem @Shawn Baek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this one of two ways.

1. Do it on GitHub and then download Working Copy. It's a free iOS app that allows you to download projects from GitHub as .playground files and run them in Swift Playgrounds.
2. Do it on a Mac. I understand this might not be possible, but it is by far the best method of doing this. It is much easier and, as a whole, better. For the best experience, I recommend this option.